# Run nscd in multiple network namespaces

Tags: linux, linux-networking, daemon, multiple-instances, network-namespace

How to run an instance of nscd daemon per network namespace? I did the following:

```
ip netns exec <network_namespace> /usr/sbin/nscd
```

However, it threw output

```
/usr/sbin/nscd: already running
```

The intention for an instance of nscd per namepace is this:

> Each network namespace has separate host files (/etc/hosts,
>   /etc/resolv.conf) and modifying these host files should trigger the
>   nscd daemon to clear the nscd cache.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to use containers as if they were VPSes.  Don't do that.

Comment: I agree with @MadHatter , Why do you want to have multiple nscd instances running in the first place ?